# Hide the question by the user who posted it if there are no answers posted

Tags: feature-request

There were few times when I posted quite a long and complicated question, after few hours when nobody answered new circumstances have arised(I *fixed/changed/partialy solved* my problem). In this case I don't want anybody to waste his time on trying to answer my question as it is partialy outdated.

I should edit my question but I am in the middle of the fight with the bug therefore until I reach next dead end editing my question is pointless.

Should I just delete my question then and post modified version later or maybe be able to hide it **ONLY** if there are no answers yet?

Comment: You can delete it, edit later, and undelete

Comment: @codeMagic I thought that deleted posts disappear permanently after a  short time. If this is not the case, you're right.

Comment: They do but I don't think it's really a "short" time (though that's a relative terms). I'll try to find what the length is. I can't remember off-hand but I think 6 months or 60 days. There's definitely a 6 in it so my mind isn't totally gone yet :P

Comment: [60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/225304)

Comment: Delete it, and if you have a new question later, post a new question. We're not trying to conserve internet, there's no need to be frugal with it by recycling.

Comment: @codeMagic & Yoda [Self-deleted questions must be undeleted before the author can edit them.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (See the first sentence in the "How can I undelete one of my posts?" section.) So, Yoda, if you do this method make sure you edit in a text editor so when you undelete you can just copy the edited question over! It's not a bug if you get an error that you cannot edit the deleted question.

Comment: @Kendra thanks, I missed that. I thought they worked the same as answers

Answer (score -1):

You can also just leave a comment saying that as a result of continuing troubleshooting, you are no longer sure whether the original explanation is wholly accurate.  Giving a short summary of the newer contrary findings is even better.

Comment: Deleting is better than leaving open with a comment. It's not going to help anybody, and the Community user periodically bumps unanswered questions to the front page. Questions that can't help anyone also risk down votes.